# ftp_nlist is not working on live

Tags: php, file, filezilla

I have following code

```
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server, $ftp_server_port); 
$raw = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass) or die('could not login.');
$raw = ftp_pasv($conn_id, true) or die('could not enable passive mode.');
$raw = ftp_nlist($conn_id, ".");    
print_r($raw); exit;
```

this is working fine on local server, but this is not working on Live server.

Any suggestion ?

Comment: Please explain "not working". Any error messages, output etc?

Comment: There is now warning or error message. On var_dump() it is giving "boolean:false"

Comment: have you tried to var_dump the result of error_get_last() after ftp_nlist() to see if there is an error?

Comment: Can you connect (and list directory) on the FTP server using a standalone FTP client running on the same machine as your PHP code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is fixed now. There was problem with PORT on the server.